# Scrapy shell returning blank array with steam website?

Tags: python, scrapy

I've used scrapy before to some success with craiglist, but now that I'm trying to scrape steam for user names arbitrarily, I keep getting a blank array in the scrapy shell.

The user name element (which is xempy for example) is contained in:

```
<a class="searchPersonaName" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/zxZEmpy">xempy</a>
```

the command I'm using to scrape the actual user names from the URL above is:

```
response.select('//*[@id="search_results"]/div[3]/div[3]/a/text()').extract()
```

the URL I'm attempting to scrape is

```
https://steamcommunity.com/search/users/#filter=users&text=xempy
```

I used Chrome to copy the xpath of the element I'm interested in instead of typing it by hand to make sure it was free of typos, but even typing it all out by hand, with the absolute paths, I still get a blank array, when i'm attempting to get a simple string with the user name "xempy".

What am I doing wrong? i've used the same process to successfully scrape craigslist, but on steam's website it doesn't seem to be working and I can't find any actual examples of steam scrapy scripts.

Comment: run  `view(response)` from the shell, also look at the actual source in your browser, right click and choose view source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you  look at the actual source in your browser, right click and choose view source you will see no sign of the results, the data is dynamically added through an ajax request to *https://steamcommunity.com/search/SearchCommunityAjax*.

You will have to mimic the ajax request, I have used requests but the steps will be the same for scrapy:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
params = {"text": "xempy", "filter": "users", "sessionid": "", "steamid_user": "false", "page": "1"}
ajax_url = "https://steamcommunity.com/search/SearchCommunityAjax"
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update()
    r = s.get("https://steamcommunity.com/search/users/#filter=users&text=xempy")
    # need to update the session id which we get from the previous gets headers
    params["sessionid"] = next(
        c.split("=", 1)[1] for c in r.headers["set-cookie"].split(";") if c.startswith("sessionid"))
    # need to update the session headers
    s.headers.update(r.headers)
    # and also the cookies from the previous request
    s.cookies.update(r.cookies)
    result = (s.get(ajax_url, params=params).json())
```

If we run the code you can see we get some json returned:

```
In [5]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ...:         s.headers.update()
   ...:         r = s.get("https://steamcommunity.com/search/users/#filter=users&text=xempy")
   ...:         params["sessionid"] = next(
   ...:             c.split("=", 1)[1] for c in r.headers["set-cookie"].split(";") if c.startswith("sessionid"))
   ...:         s.headers.update(r.headers)
   ...:         s.cookies.update(r.cookies)
   ...:         result = (s.get(ajax_url, params=params).json())
   ...:         print(result)
   ...:     
{u'html': u'\t\t<div style="float: right; padding-bottom: 2px">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tShowing 1 - 11 of 11\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear: both"></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="search_row">\r\n\t<div class="search_result_friend">\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div class="mediumHolder_default" data-miniprofile="16183171" style="float:left;"><div class="avatarMedium"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/zxZEmpy"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/b9/b9c886a08cf17c4f1f31ea19148d8b3bbd748762_medium.jpg"></a></div></div>\r\n\t<div class="searchPersonaInfo">\r\n\t\t<a class="searchPersonaName" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/zxZEmpy">xempy</a><br />\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t&nbsp;\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear:left"></div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<div class="search_match_info">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>Custom URL: steamcommunity.com/id/<span style="color: whitesmoke">zxZEmpy</span></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAlso known as: <span style="color: whitesmoke">trill</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">[TGIF] Mario Batali</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">[TGIF] Mario \xdfatali</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">Mario \xdfatali</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">[TGIF\'</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">[TGIF] Mario \u03b2atali</span>\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="search_row">\r\n\t<div class="search_result_friend">\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div class="mediumHolder_default" data-miniprofile="280326130" style="float:left;"><div class="avatarMedium"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/xempyjecar"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/89/8928b324ba9c12859283e8be3f11f19d9232033c_medium.jpg"></a></div></div>\r\n\t<div class="searchPersonaInfo">\r\n\t\t<a class="searchPersonaName" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/xempyjecar">Xempy -A-</a><br />\r\n\t\t\t\t\tIgor<br />\t\t\tSerbia&nbsp;<img style="margin-bottom:-2px" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/countryflags/rs.gif" border="0" />\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear:left"></div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<div class="search_match_info">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>Custom URL: steamcommunity.com/id/<span style="color: whitesmoke">xempyjecar</span></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAlso known as: <span style="color: whitesmoke">Xempy -A- NEW SEASON HYPEE</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">Brekija</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">FAIRPLAY ORGANISATION</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">Xempy | csgoshit.com</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">Xempy | csgorage.com</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2554\u2550\u2550\u2550\u2557</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">XempyTheCupcake</span>\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="search_row">\r\n\t<div class="search_result_friend">\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div class="mediumHolder_default" data-miniprofile="315139919" style="float:left;"><div class="avatarMedium"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/filipppp"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/ca/caa5747851b5255a2d76699d855bf20e709af3d1_medium.jpg"></a></div></div>\r\n\t<div class="searchPersonaInfo">\r\n\t\t<a class="searchPersonaName" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/filipppp">Xempy -A-</a><br />\r\n\t\t\t\t\tIgor<br />\t\t\tSerbia&nbsp;<img style="margin-bottom:-2px" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/countryflags/rs.gif" border="0" />\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear:left"></div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<div class="search_match_info">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>Custom URL: steamcommunity.com/id/<span style="color: whitesmoke">filipppp</span></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAlso known as: <span style="color: whitesmoke">Extreeemeeee</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">Ratatatatatata</span>\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="search_row">\r\n\t<div class="search_result_friend">\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div class="mediumHolder_default" data-miniprofile="258386073" style="float:left;"><div class="avatarMedium"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/lenyagoglov"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/71/71ee8d0519c74cea0352836b188c747b36224f8f_medium.jpg"></a></div></div>\r\n\t<div class="searchPersonaInfo">\r\n\t\t<a class="searchPersonaName" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/lenyagoglov">Xempys</a><br />\r\n\t\t\t\t\tTed<br />\t\t\tLuxembourg&nbsp;<img style="margin-bottom:-2px" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/countryflags/lu.gif" border="0" />\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear:left"></div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<div class="search_match_info">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>Custom URL: steamcommunity.com/id/<span style="color: whitesmoke">lenyagoglov</span></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="search_row">\r\n\t<div class="search_result_friend">\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div class="mediumHolder_default" data-miniprofile="257927191" style="float:left;"><div class="avatarMedium"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/rostislavtseychuk85"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/86/8641de85a283f0d23d1cbeb35ee0c0d5ca87a83b_medium.jpg"></a></div></div>\r\n\t<div class="searchPersonaInfo">\r\n\t\t<a class="searchPersonaName" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/rostislavtseychuk85">Xempys</a><br />\r\n\t\t\t\t\tGabriel<br />\t\t\tLebanon&nbsp;<img style="margin-bottom:-2px" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/countryflags/lb.gif" border="0" />\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear:left"></div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<div class="search_match_info">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>Custom URL: steamcommunity.com/id/<span style="color: whitesmoke">rostislavtseychuk85</span></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="search_row">\r\n\t<div class="search_result_friend">\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div class="mediumHolder_default" data-miniprofile="252811169" style="float:left;"><div class="avatarMedium"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/mochulskayaa"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/76/76c10b0744403468aaf8090f56ca8ddd61338925_medium.jpg"></a></div></div>\r\n\t<div class="searchPersonaInfo">\r\n\t\t<a class="searchPersonaName" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/mochulskayaa">Xempys</a><br />\r\n\t\t\t\t\tRichard<br />\t\t\tGuatemala&nbsp;<img style="margin-bottom:-2px" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/countryflags/gt.gif" border="0" />\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear:left"></div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<div class="search_match_info">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>Custom URL: steamcommunity.com/id/<span style="color: whitesmoke">mochulskayaa</span></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="search_row">\r\n\t<div class="search_result_friend">\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div class="mediumHolder_default" data-miniprofile="260028611" style="float:left;"><div class="avatarMedium"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/katerukhina"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/24/24241e97a6caf3bd932a01ea22afc6b3d758f1a1_medium.jpg"></a></div></div>\r\n\t<div class="searchPersonaInfo">\r\n\t\t<a class="searchPersonaName" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/katerukhina">Xempys</a><br />\r\n\t\t\t\t\tChristian<br />\t\t\tFiji&nbsp;<img style="margin-bottom:-2px" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/countryflags/fj.gif" border="0" />\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear:left"></div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<div class="search_match_info">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>Custom URL: steamcommunity.com/id/<span style="color: whitesmoke">katerukhina</span></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="search_row">\r\n\t<div class="search_result_friend">\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div class="mediumHolder_default" data-miniprofile="292454844" style="float:left;"><div class="avatarMedium"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/purdenkos"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/5c/5c7f9d1b71a68ab8599ae0fe8f2c4e0445348eaa_medium.jpg"></a></div></div>\r\n\t<div class="searchPersonaInfo">\r\n\t\t<a class="searchPersonaName" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/purdenkos">Xempys</a><br />\r\n\t\t\t\t\tPatrik<br />\t\t\tCote D\'ivoire (Ivory Coast)&nbsp;<img style="margin-bottom:-2px" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/countryflags/ci.gif" border="0" />\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear:left"></div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<div class="search_match_info">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>Custom URL: steamcommunity.com/id/<span style="color: whitesmoke">purdenkos</span></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="search_row">\r\n\t<div class="search_result_friend">\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div class="mediumHolder_default" data-miniprofile="56000172" style="float:left;"><div class="avatarMedium"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/v2incent"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/ac/ac45a256e0a14712efff255db0105fedd80a4f0e_medium.jpg"></a></div></div>\r\n\t<div class="searchPersonaInfo">\r\n\t\t<a class="searchPersonaName" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/v2incent">Ext4ze ` ^0| \'Xempy^0\'</a><br />\r\n\t\t\t\t\tv2incent<br />\t\t\t&nbsp;\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear:left"></div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<div class="search_match_info">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>Custom URL: steamcommunity.com/id/<span style="color: whitesmoke">v2incent</span></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="search_row">\r\n\t<div class="search_result_friend">\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div class="mediumHolder_default" data-miniprofile="297670812" style="float:left;"><div class="avatarMedium"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/xempy"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/62/62ea583f7f838562c73cb70e3993e27acd583aef_medium.jpg"></a></div></div>\r\n\t<div class="searchPersonaInfo">\r\n\t\t<a class="searchPersonaName" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/xempy">xempsanity `\xb4</a><br />\r\n\t\t\t\t\tIgor<br />\t\t\tSerbia&nbsp;<img style="margin-bottom:-2px" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/countryflags/rs.gif" border="0" />\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear:left"></div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<div class="search_match_info">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>Custom URL: steamcommunity.com/id/<span style="color: whitesmoke">xempy</span></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAlso known as: <span style="color: whitesmoke">XEMPYKiNGOFNOTHiNG</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">X3MPY</span>, <span style="color: whitesmoke">X3MPY * brother\'s on acc</span>\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="search_row">\r\n\t<div class="search_result_friend">\r\n\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div class="mediumHolder_default" data-miniprofile="121633219" style="float:left;"><div class="avatarMedium"><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/Empyrk"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/6b/6b87d7a04bf211a2665b828436ad34e549f2b193_medium.jpg"></a></div></div>\r\n\t<div class="searchPersonaInfo">\r\n\t\t<a class="searchPersonaName" href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/Empyrk">Empyrk</a><br />\r\n\t\t\t\t\tMatteo<br />\t\t\tToscana, Italy&nbsp;<img style="margin-bottom:-2px" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/countryflags/it.gif" border="0" />\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear:left"></div>\r\n\r\n\t\t\t<div class="search_match_info">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div>Custom URL: steamcommunity.com/id/<span style="color: whitesmoke">Empyrk</span></div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t\t\t\t<div style="clear: both"></div>\r\n\t\t<div style="float: right; padding-bottom: 2px">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tShowing 1 - 11 of 11\t\t\t</div>\r\n\t<div style="clear: both"></div>\r\n\r\n\r\n', u'search_filter': u'users', u'search_text': u'xempy', u'success': 1, u'search_page': 1}
```

You just need to access `results["html"]` to get the source.